# Howto modify this short php-function? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wpml

This function is part of the WMPL-Plugin (Language-Selector) for Wordpress. What I need is a extension (if / else) of this function which makes it possible to show another flag-image on active sites.

```
function language_selector_flags(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
    if(!empty($languages)){
        foreach($languages as $l){
            if(!$l['active']) echo '<a href="'.$l['url'].'">';
            echo '<img src="'.$l['country_flag_url'].'" height="12" 
            alt="'.$l['language_code'].'" width="18" />';
            if(!$l['active']) echo '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS isn't a problem, but my php-skills are on a very low level. It would be great if anyone can tell me a solution. Thanks for your helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
function language_selector_flags(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
    if(!empty($languages)){
        foreach($languages as $l){
            if(!$l['active']) echo '<a href="'.$l['url'].'">';
            if($l['active']){
                echo '<img src="'.ACTIVE_FLAG_URL.'" height="12" alt="'.$l['language_code'].'" width="18" />';
            }else{
                echo '<img src="'.$l['country_flag_url'].'" height="12" alt="'.$l['language_code'].'" width="18" />';
            }
            if(!$l['active']) echo '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

You need to substitute "ACTIVE_FLAG_URL" with your own URL.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only if the active image is always the same. I think I need a modification of country_flag_url like country_flag_url +_active (= en_active.png, es_active_png ...) My problem is that country_flag_url includes the full file name (e.g. en.png)